# Tensorflow: CNN training converges at a vector of zeros

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

I'm a beginner in deep learning and have taken a few courses on Udacity. Recently I'm trying to build a deep network detecting hand joints in the input depth images, which doesn't seem to be working well. (My dataset is ICVL Hand Posture Dataset)
[The network structure is shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Wrc.png)

① A batch of input images, 240x320;

② An 8-channel convolutional layer with a 5x5 kernel;

③ A max pooling layer, ksize = stride = 2;

④ A fully-connected layer, weight.shape = [38400, 1024];

⑤ A fully-connected layer, weight.shape = [1024, 48].

After several epochs of training, the output of the last layer converges as a (0, 0, ..., 0) vector. I chose the mean square error as the loss function and its value stayed above 40000 and didn't seem to reduce.

The network structure is already too simple to be simplified again but the problem remains. Could anyone offer any suggestions?

My main code is posted below:

```
image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 240, 320, 1])
annotations = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 48])

W_convolution_layer1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 1, 8], stddev=0.1))
b_convolution_layer1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[8]))
h_convolution_layer1 = tf.nn.relu(
    tf.nn.conv2d(image, W_convolution_layer1, [1, 1, 1, 1], 'SAME') + b_convolution_layer1)
h_pooling_layer1 = tf.nn.max_pool(h_convolution_layer1, [1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2, 1], 'SAME')

W_fully_connected_layer1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([120 * 160 * 8, 1024], stddev=0.1))
b_fully_connected_layer1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[1024]))
h_pooling_flat = tf.reshape(h_pooling_layer1, [-1, 120 * 160 * 8])
h_fully_connected_layer1 = tf.nn.relu(
    tf.matmul(h_pooling_flat, W_fully_connected_layer1) + b_fully_connected_layer1)

W_fully_connected_layer2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1024, 48], stddev=0.1))
b_fully_connected_layer2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[48]))
detection = tf.nn.relu(
    tf.matmul(h_fully_connected_layer1, W_fully_connected_layer2) + b_fully_connected_layer2)

mean_squared_error = tf.reduce_sum(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(annotations, detection))
training = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(mean_squared_error)
# This data loader reads images and annotations and convert them into batches of numbers.
loader = ICVLDataLoader('../data/')

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(1000):
        # batch_images: a list with shape = [BATCH_SIZE, 240, 320, 1]
        # batch_annotations: a list with shape = [BATCH_SIZE, 48]
        [batch_images, batch_annotations] = loader.get_batch(100).to_1d_list()
        [x_, t_, l_, p_] = session.run([x_image, training, mean_squared_error, detection],
                                       feed_dict={images: batch_images, annotations: batch_annotations})
```

And it runs like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvO4m.png).

Comment: Please show your code. Sounds like a bug in the implementation somewhere.

Comment: I have re-edited the question and posted my code. Thanks a lot.@xdurch0

Comment: Thank you, that helps. One more thing to clarify: What are the targets? I.e. apparently there are 48 target values, but what do they represent? Is this a classification problem? If so, does each input belong to exactly one class (i.e. targets are one-hot vectors) or can multiple of the 48 values be 1 for a single input?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details. This is a detection problem, where the 48 target values stand for (x, y, z) coordinates of the 16 key points of the hand at the center of the depth image. I never dealt with detection problems so maybe I made some really funny mistakes.@xdurch0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is likely the `relu` activation in the output layer. You should remove this, i.e. let `detection` simply be the results of a matrix multiplication. If you want to force the outputs to be positive, consider something like the exponential function instead.

While `relu` is a popular hidden activation, I see one major problem with using it as an output activation: As is well known `relu` maps negative inputs to 0 -- however, crucially, the *gradients* will also be 0. This happening in the output layer basically means your network cannot learn from its mistakes when it produces outputs < 0 (which is likely to happen with random initializations). This will likely heavily impair the overall learning process.